# Conditional promises in Ember.RSVP

Tags: javascript, ember.js, rsvp.js, rsvp-promise

I have a simple if else scenario where I need to do something if a variable is set otherwise just perform in the else part:

```
if(flag) {
  doSomething();
}
doNextThing(someParam);
```

If flag is set, then I must doSomething() and doNextThing()

Both doSomething and doNextThing return promises. What is the best way to implement this?

Currently my code looks like:

```
if(flag) {
  doSomething().then(doNextThing);
} 
else doNextThing(someParam);
```

What is the best way to elegantly combine the two in cleaner code segment?

I tried:

```
var somePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     if(flag)
        doSomething.then(resolve(result));
      else resolve();
})

return somePromise.then(doNextThing(resolvedValue))
```

but this doesn't work. Seems like the promise doSomething is never resolve and the code returns immediately. I also tried several variations of the above including:

```
var somePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     if(flag)
        doSomething.then(resolve);
      else resolve();
})
```

and:

```
var somePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     if(flag)
        doSomething.then(function(result){
             resolve(result);
        }.bind(this));
      else resolve();
}.bind(this));
```

but nothing works, except for the very first option. So, my question is - Is there a better/elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: You should accept one of the answers or at least explain why you not accepted none of them.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
Em.RSVP.allSettled([
    !flag || doSomething(),
    doNextThing()
])
```

It will try each item in the array, but skipping the first if the flag is false.  If you want it to skip doNextThing() if doSomething() fails, then use Em.RSVP.all().

Answer (score 0):

Try moving to `Ember.RSVP.Promise` and returning promise in your function (it should chain them):

```
var somePromise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     if (flag) {
         return doSomething;
     }
     resolve();
});

return somePromise.then(doNextThing);
```

Answer (score 0):

One elegant way of doing this:

```
var firstThing = flag ? doSomething() : Ember.RSVP.resolve();
firstThing.then(doNextThing.bind(null, someParam));
```

If you look in the `then` function I am using the bind function to create a partially applied function.

This is because the function `then` expects a function as his argument, so you can't call it like this `firstThing.then(doNextThing(param))`. This way you are passing the result of the function, not the function.